# How to perform this MySQL query given this relation diagram

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have the following relation diagram where arrows represent Foreign Keys. The word in the blue is the table name and the words below are column names.

[image]

My question is how I could extract the following data from this table:

-what is the GPA of the student with ID=1?

-what are the average GPAs for students by department?

Given that: there are only
five letter grades with values A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, and F=0, and GPA is the sum of
course credits x course grade value divided by total credits x 4. (so takes.grade is an int from 0-4 inclusive).

I have been trying to figure this out for hours with no avail. Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please put a little effort into your question by showing what you have been working on before expecting SO to do your homework problems for you.

Comment: This seems like a homework question to me...

Comment: You are correct. This is a homework question. I am just looking for guidance. My first instinct was to try to join course and takes on course_id and takes and student on ID but I did not get the result I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've actually had to do this for a client over 15 yrs ago, and did for the entire database of all students, not as difficult once you have the pieces.

Without your exact queries as you want guidance.

Start with a single query that pulls data into a TEMPORARY table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AllStudentsCourses
SELECT blah... from blah... join blah.. where... order by ...
```

A list of all classes a person has signed up for, and while you are at it, have columns computed at the PER-CLASS BASIS the grade earned A-F.  You'll also need the credit hours of the class too as that is basis of computing a GPA.

a 3 hour course with an A gets 3 cr hrs towards GPA.
a 6 hour course with an A gets 6 cr hrs towards GPA.
a 6 hour course with a B gets LESS weighted value towards GPA 
and you'll need to roll aggregates up.

Now, once you have all the classes a student attempted, you'll need to compute the per-class as sample described.  If you want to apply that in the first query, do so.

Once you have that, then, you can roll-up the total credit hrs attempted vs credit hrs earned.

Basic math should help you along.

Comment: Thanks! So would this be the outline of the calculation of GPA (just what I'm to be selecting assuming i've joined the tables correctly)?
SUM(credits*grade)/(s.tot_cred*4)

Comment: @user1170679, not EXACTLY... close, but not exactly... Take a look at http://www.rackham.umich.edu/admissions/frequently_asked_questions/how_do_i_compute_my_us_gpa/ which shows basis of computing GPAs.  Different places weigh grades slightly different.  So for you, you need to apply the known "letter" grade to its corresponding weight...

Comment: Awesome! So I believe the solution I am looking for is:

SELECT SUM(credits*grade)/SUM(credits) FROM Takes t INNER JOIN Course c ON t.course_id = c.course_id INNER JOIN Student s ON s.ID = t.ID WHERE t.ID = 1;

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand how the GPA is calculated, think there is something wrong with your original post. Here's a starting point that may or may not be right:

```
SELECT avg(t.grade) 
FROM takes t 
   INNER JOIN course c 
   ON t.course_id = c.course_id 
WHERE t.ID = 1;

SELECT c.dept_name, avg(grade)
FROM takes t 
    INNER JOIN course c 
    ON t.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY c.dept_name
```

Comment: ha :)  yup, you don't understand how GPA is computed... Average is NOT a basis of computing GPA.

Comment: In my part of the world we don't have GPA (we have something else), hence why I'm not sure.